# How to read specific line value from a website?

Tags: java, html, bufferedreader

Following code read whole data set from a website.But I want to read specific value record from a web site. As a example when I pass a word to a website it dynamically display weather the word which I entered was what kind of word.When I pass tree name this return biographical name.I want to read that biographical name.Not the all data set of a website.How should I change?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DataRecord {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of some data on a website and what your expected output is(the data you want to isolate)? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Actually I don't want to read whole data set of a website.Because that have lot of data. I want specific dynamic output from that site only.Above code read whole data.Ex:I enter "Jak Tree".That site return biographical name of Jak tree.I want to read and get that name only from that site.

Comment: So do you just want the line that contains "Jak Tree"? I don't mean to be rude, but you are not being very clear.  Can you edit you r post to include an example of a website and a screenshot with a box around the data you want?

Comment: I want actually read return name of "Jak Tree". That site return that biographical name of I entered tree.Sorry dear.I'm not that much of fluent in English.

Comment: I understand I'm trying to help, can you post the website so we can see it?

Comment: Thnx dear. As a example http://dictionary.reference.com return weather I entered word is noun or verb or adjective.I want to read that things."noun or verb or adjective" like that.Not all data of that site.

Comment: Can you use library like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for this?